# How to fix 'CURLFile' function not found error?

Tags: php, api, curl, marketo

I am trying to implement marketo create file rest API. But i am getting 'Class CURLFile not found' error due to my php version. So please help how i can use 'CURLFile' funtion in lower php or is their any another equivalent of same function. Please check my below code:-

```
<?php
$file = new CreateFile();
$file->file = new CURLFile("File.txt", "text/plain", "file");
$file->folder = new stdClass();
$file->folder->id = 5565;
$file->folder->type = "Folder";
$file->name = "Test File.txt";
print_r($file->postData());

class CreateFile{
    private $host = "CHANGE ME";
    private $clientId = "CHANGE ME";
    private $clientSecret = "CHANGE ME";
    public $name;//name of file to create, required
    public $file;//CURLFile of file to input
    public $folder;//json object with two members, id and type(Folder or Program)
    public $description;//option description of file
    public $insertOnly;//boolean option to only perform an Insert

    public function postData(){
        $url = $this->host . "/rest/asset/v1/files.json?access_token=" . $this->getToken();
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $requestBody = $this->bodyBuilder();
        curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json','Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
        curl_getinfo($ch);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        return $response;
    }

    private function getToken(){
        $ch = curl_init($this->host . "/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" . $this->clientId . "&client_secret=" . $this->clientSecret);
        curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json',));
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
        $token = $response->access_token;
        return $token;
    }
    private function bodyBuilder(){
        $requestBody = array("file" => $this->file, "name" => $this->name, "folder" => json_encode($this->folder));
        if (isset($this->description)){
            $requestBody["description"] = $this->description;
        }
        if(isset($this->insertOnly)){
            $requestBody["insertOnly"] = $this->insertOnly;
        }
        return $requestBody;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace `$file->file = new CURLFile("File.txt", "text/plain", "file");`

with `$file->file = "@File.txt;filename=file;type=text/plain";`

in php 5.5+ you need to set `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);`

Comment: Works ! Thank you. This is like a polyfill for older php versions.

Comment: "curl_setopt(): Disabling safe uploads is no longer supported

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PHP version >=5.5 and a framework like Laravel, remember to add "\" before CURLFILE.

Comment: still works as of Laravel 10

Answer (score 3):

> new CURLFile("File.txt", "text/plain", "file");

1. Need a `\` when creating the CURLFile object as without the `\` it looks for this namespace locally rather than globally.
2. The first param needs to be the server's path.

   Ex: `/var/www/html/File.text`

   You could use the PHP [realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function to append the `/var/www/html/` part for you.

---

#### Solution

```
$file_server_path = realpath(File.text);
$file->file = new \CURLFile($file_server_path, 'text/plain', 'file');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check you PHP version.
CURLFile is only work for the PHP version => 5.5

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides certain functionality by way of loadable modules. This is most often the case for things that require extra libraries, like libcurl. In order to use that functionality, the relevant module needs to be installed on your system, and a statement to load the relevant module needs to appear in your `php.ini` file.

How you install the curl module depends on how you installed PHP; it may be as simple as installing the package, or it may require that you recompile all of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

File Upload w/o CURLFile Class in PHP Version < 5.5.0 don´t work. Update Your PHP Version to 5.5, 5.6, 7.0, 7.1. Then it works.