# how to send file from server to telegram bot php

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send an APK file from my server (URL) to my telegram bot

```
<?php 
    if ($update->callback_query->data == "app_dl"){
        $chat_id = $update->callback_query->message->chat->id;
        $document = "BQADBAAD2wADHg4hUfbD3f-YYGc3Ag";
        $caption = "text";
        var_dump(
            makeHTTPRequest('sendDocument',[
                'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
                'document'=> $document,
                'caption'=> $caption
            ])
        );  
    }
?>
```

I tried this one and send one APK file from telegram server to my bot
but I want to send one APK file from my server to boot

Answer (score 0):

If [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is enabled ([check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433965/4438683)), you could try this:

```
$filePath = 'myfile.apk'; // Relative path to a file in current directory
$document = new CURLFile(realpath($filePath));
```

Works perfect for me but you could also [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990390/4438683) if it doesn't work for you.