# PHP new CURLFile in curl 7.22 doesn't work, why?

Tags: php, curl

below is my code:

```
$urlToWa = 'XXX:XX:XXX:XX:XXXX/recruit/sendEmailWithFile?to='.$mail.'&name='.$name;
  $ch = curl_init($urlToWa);
      print_r($_FILES['file']);  
      $cfile = new CURLFile($_FILES['file']['type'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
      // $_SESSION['plikObr'] = $cfile;
      $data = array("file" => $cfile);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlToWa);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'request:nowChuckyNextSamara');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

And i have some problem with creating CURLFile. In the second server i have the same script and everything work well. 
On the server where is above script i have curl library in 7.22 version, and on the second server where everythings work i have curl in 7.47 version.

Where is the problem?
Thanks for herp

Comment: please provide error.

Comment: This is internal error (500):  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CURLFile' not found

Comment: please refer this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990249/how-to-fix-curlfile-function-not-found-error

Comment: Ok thanks, everythings work well :)